# How to delete a specific row after a click | Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a table with orders that is automatically generated and looks like this:

[image]

```
function orderHandlers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/order",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            const states = {
                "new": "Не оплачен",
                "paid": "Оплачен",
                "assembly": "В сборке",
                "delivery": "В доставке",
                "delivered": "Доставлен",
                "disputed": "Оспаривается"
            }


            for (let item of data) {
                if (item.timestamp) item.datetime = new Date(item.timestamp).toLocaleString('ru-RU');
                item.state = states[item.order] || "Неизвестен";
                item.amount = item.amount + ' ₽';
                item.actions = '';
                
                if (item.state === 'Не оплачен') {
                        item.actions = `
                    <a href="./orderCancel.html"  class="item-action-btn"> Отменить заказ </a>
                    `;
                    }
                    if ((item.state === 'Оплачен') || (item.state === 'В сборке') || (item.state === 'В доставке')) {
                        item.actions = "";
                    }
                    if (item.state === 'В сборке') {
                        item.actions = `<a href="" class="item-action-btn"> Задать вопрос </a>`;
                    }
                    if (item.state === 'Доставлен') {
                        item.actions = `<a href="" class="item-action-btn"> Связаться с менеджером </a>`;
                }
            }

            $('.catalog-message').hide();

            console.log('[Orders]', data);
            renderTable('#user-orders', data, [{
                    data: '_id'
                },
                {
                    data: 'datetime'
                },
                {
                    data: 'state'
                },
                {
                    data: 'amount'
                },
                {
                    data: 'actions'
                }
            ]);

            

            $('#user-orders').show();
        },
        error: function(error) {
            renderTable('#user-order', [], []);
            console.log('[Error]', error.responseText);
            showToast(error.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see I have added a link for a cancelation option but I can't get my head around this: **how do I actually cancel (pop this object out of Orders array) the order when I click on one of the 'Cancel order' buttons**

Edit: added a pic of the table

Comment: which do you don't understand? onclick? how to remove an item from an array? or how to rerender the table?

Comment: Just noticed you appear to be using R Shiny, is that correct?

Comment: @Lucretius hi there! no, I'm not using R Shiny. The table is generated automatically when I pass the payment page. Then it creates an array of objects where each one is the order.

Comment: @webdeb hi! I do not understand how to remove an order by clicking on the Cancel order link. I need to be able to click on the button in the row that I want to be removed from the array.

Comment: your orders are stored on the server side, so you want to remove it on the server side and then reload the table

Comment: @webdeb exactly. When the table is generated theres an ID in each row. i need somehow to send the info that I'm clicking on the link in the same row as the ID, remove it, and then return to the new table with one less item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an onclick event handler for the anchor, but you'll need to be able to get an identifier from that row if you're looking for the server side to agree with the client side.

Assuming the html looks something like this from renderTable(), I added some uniqueness to the IDs and assumed that there may be more than one row in the table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="_id1">id</td>
          <td id="datetime1">datetime</td>
          <td id="state1">state</td>
          <td id="amount1">amount</td>
          <td id="actions1">
            <a href="#" class="item-action-btn">action1</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="_id2">id</td>
          <td id="datetime2">datetime</td>
          <td id="state2">state</td>
          <td id="amount2">amount</td>
          <td id="actions2">
            <a href="#" class="item-action-btn">action2</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="_id3">id</td>
          <td id="datetime3">datetime</td>
          <td id="state3">state</td>
          <td id="amount3">amount</td>
          <td id="actions3">
            <a href="#" class="item-action-btn">action3</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below looks for any `.item-action-btn` click, logs its id to console (you could do other stuff with it), and then removes the row from the table.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.item-action-btn', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  console.log(tr.children('td:first').attr('id'));
  // maybe send this ID to the server using ajax to update cart?
  // if you wanted the text out of that initial column use this:
  console.log(tr.children('td:first').text());
  tr.remove();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mk9xep5r/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't assign IDs to every single item of the table because they're generated automatically. 
I'd like to be able to click on the link and get the ID of the element from the same row where the link was to the event handler so then it does the job and removes the obj from the array

Comment: I might be able to help more if you provided some sample html of what the output of renderTable() is doing.  Thanks,

Comment: @karinaivanova I also added an example of how to get the text from within the first `<td>` element that you labeled "ID" of the row using this:  `console.log(tr.children('td:first').text());`  (added to answer above)

Comment: it works but it doesnt remove it from the array

Comment: I think you might be using a plugin of some kind (not shiny apparently), please try to link a working https://jsfiddle.net/ that is doing most of what you would like.  It's harder when we can't see the problem.  There are lots of ways to manipulate arrays, but I can't get your code to replicate the existence of an array.  https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/karina4840/xm6nzcqe/3/